# Issues using static library which uses another static library as its dependency

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries

IDE: Visual Studio 2015

I am building a static library which serves as an http api client (`client.lib`), which in turn uses another static library `cpprestsdk.lib` that it uses for networking. I can compile this just fine and looking at the size of `client.lib` it seems it properly contains its dependencies statically.

Now when I try to use `client.lib` in a new Win32 console application it gives me lots of [LNK2001](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LNK2001)&rd=true) errors and [LNK2038](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LNK2038)&rd=true) errors.

1. Can I even use a single static library which includes another static library itself?
2. Do I need to include the header files of the `cpprestsdk` library too inside a program that uses `client.lib`?

Could someone link me or explain to me how you properly use a static link library which has other static linked libraries in itself?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Static libraries don't get linked, and so don't take dependencies on other libraries. They simply have unresolved external symbols, which need to be resolved when the executable is ultimately linked. So your EXE needs to link both with `client.lib` and `cpprestsdk.lib`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for your answer! I was hoping it would be possible to ultimately "embed" them into one .lib file. I guess that is where the "librarian" is for in VS. I would like to separate those implementation details away from the end program itself.

Comment: Static libs are, essentially, archives of `obj` files, not much different from, say, `zip` files. You can use [`lib` utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ykb2k5f.aspx) to merge two static libraries into one, if you are so inclined.

Comment: Have you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17b885t.aspx? Basically you want something like `lib /out: newlib.lib client.lib cpprestsdk.lib`, but I'm not a lib expert. so this may be wrong.